# Positioning absolute element outside of the relative parent container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the element(tooltip) outside of the parent element

code sample:
You can see that when you hover on first li the tooltip is cut off.

```css
ul{
      height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    li{
      position: relative;
      height: 40px;
    }
    .tooltip{
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      bottom: 45px;
    }
    li:hover > .tooltip{
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>some data 
        <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
      </li>
      <li>some data2 
        <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
      </li>
      ...
      ...
    </ul>
```

Ok, so in the above code, when you hower on the first `li` element the `tooltip` element is cut off by the container `overflow: auto`, The auto overflow has to be there as this `ul` element will contain lots of `li` and I want user to scroll through the list items.

So my question is following: Is there a way to maintain the scroll behaviour of the `ul` element and at the same time to display the tooltip so that it is not cut off by the `ul` element?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You will need to place the tooltip element outside of the scrollable element and then display it via js then position it to a spot you want or display the tooltip in the same spot for all items.

Comment: Huangism, this solution seams a bit hacky, are you sure this can't be handled by pure css/html?.

Comment: Yea, you can also give your `ul` padding top so there is space on top to show the tooltip. You can't get around the overflow thing. There is nothing hacky about showing a tooltip in the same spot for a scrollable container

Comment: Huangism Ok, thanks for the response! Post this as an answer and I will aprove it.

Comment: Maybe wait a bit, someone else might have some better ideas or maybe you could look into a tooltip library

Comment: Huangism, Sure, there are lots of libraries that solve this problem, but I wanted to solve it with pure css/html and after doiing lots of research I think that it is not possible.

Comment: Not the way you want it to be done unless you add the padding but even that doesn't guarantee the tooltip will show completely depending on the size of the content. There is nothing wrong with using js because it is meant to work with css and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a containing element to apply scroll:

```css
.list-wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: 45px;
}

li:hover>.tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>some data
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data2
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data2
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data2
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
        <li>some data2
            <span class="tooltip">Lots of data</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```